# Error on parsing Undefined - Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

while processing a json data,

```
      if(localStorage.getItem('currentShop')!="undefined")
     selected shop = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentShop')).Id;
       //works

      if(localStorage.getItem('currentShop')!=undefined)
     selected shop = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentShop')).Id;
       // not works
```

[image]
but currentShop is "undefined"

is it currect way to handle this, how to parse "undefined" using json parser

Comment: Of course u can’t do it bcs the pop ups are part of the browser not the page. U cannot out html inside them

Comment: You need to use custom pop ups to do the following

Comment: iam working on angular material , `<input type="file" matInput>` not working well in the form-field .  that's why I tried to create a JavaScript prompt to get the file from user .mm ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prompts are controlled by the browser. You can only provide a string to them. You can check the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) for more details.